# Code Formatting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

Is there some combination of keys or a menu option that I can use to automatically format my code in Visual Studio?

Comment: @Jan Jongboom - pretty print = getting VS to format/indent your code so it looks nice.

Comment: You talk about formatting your source? If so, use `ctrl + e, d`.

Comment: thanks guys - you all helped a lot with this.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It sounds like you want to format the entire document in Visual Studio (this feature is some times referred to as pretty printing).  If so then you can use the menu command. `Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document`.  This is typically bound to the key stroke <kbd>CTRL+K</kbd><kbd>CTRL+D</kbd>

Comment: ... and what if your Visual Studio is not configured yet for code formatting? (I have a brand new laptop here, and I assume that code formatting rules are not present (yet).)

Comment: For those of us who do not have the 'Advanced' option on the Edit menu, you can use Help ->  Show all commands  ->  Format Document.

Answer (score 7):

You could try the [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) extension to Visual Studio.

This does [code cleaning](http://www.codemaid.net/documentation/#cleaning) with the following steps:

1. Remove unused using statements
2. Sort using statements
3. Add unspecified access modifiers
4. Add blank line padding
5. Remove blank lines adjacent to braces
6. **Run Visual Studio formatting**
7. Remove consecutive blank lines
8. Remove end of line whitespace
9. Update endregion tags

So you get Visual Studio's built-in reformatting plus lots of other tidying in one go. I expect there are other tools that do the same thing. I've been using CodeMaid for a while now and it's both fast and reliable.

Comment: THanks, I was looking for this. I wanted something that can clean up my extra line breaks (and also add in line breaks).

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio Code it's `Shift+Alt+F`. Note that the chording order is important.

[vscode](/questions/tagged/vscode)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean to format and indent the document nicely.

**ctrl +E,D**

Answer (score 3):

If you really meant what JaredPar and Glenn are meaning you could also think about installing the [PowerCommands for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99/).

After that you can go to `Tools - Options - PowerCommand` and enable the `Format document on save`. This will call the mentioned method always when you save the document, thus leading to an always good formatted document.

Also you should know that the keystroke of JaredPar and Glenn are not always working. Depending on what you selected at the first start of Visual Studio (are you a C#, VB, Web or Generic programmer) the keystrokes are slightly different.

If you selected C# developer the answer of Glenn and JaredPar works. If you selected generic or C++ developer only JaredPar answer works. If you took another *role* than maybe none of these keystrokes works and you have to check your keystroke through the menu at the position JaredPar mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Bit late, but if you have ReSharper you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean to format and indent the document nicely.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>